# Uninitialized constant API on rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Following [this tutorial](http://funonrails.com/2014/03/building-restful-api-using-grape-in-rails/#disqus_thread), I created the API of my existing blog web application on Rails. I am getting the error:

> uninitialized constant API

This is my code:

`lib/api/v1/articles.rb`:

```
module API
 module V1
   class Articles < Grape::API
  version 'v1'
  format :json

  resource :articles do
    desc "Return list of recent posts"
    get do
     Article.recent.all
    end
  end
 end
end
end
```

`lib/api/v1/root/rb`

```
module API
 module V1
 class Root < Grape::API
  mount API::V1::Articles
     end
 end
end
```

`lib/api/root.rb`

```
module API
class Root < Grape::API
    prefix 'api'
    mount API::V1::Root
    end
end
```

`lib/tasks/routes.rake`

```
namespace :api do
  desc "API Routes"
  task :routes => :environment do
   API::Root.routes.each do |api|
  method = api.route_method.ljust(10)
  path = api.route_path.gsub(":version", api.route_version)
  puts "     #{method} #{path}"
 end
end
end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount API::Root => '/'
 get 'welcome/index'
 root 'welcome#index'
  resources :articles
  end
```

This is the existing web application code:

`app/controllers/articles_controller.rb`

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
def new
end
def create
   # render plain: params[:article].inspect
     @article = Article.new(article_params)

 @article.save
 redirect_to @article
    end
def show
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
private

def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title,:text)
    end

end
```

Now I'm in the `Accessing API routes` part of this article. When I run rake routes it gives the error, uninitialized constant API.. What I'm doing wrong.

**Edit**: As per the comment, giving the detailed error

```
rake aborted!
NameError: Uninitialized constant API
F:/blog/config/routes.rb:2:in 'block in <top (required)>'
F:/blog/config/routes.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
C:in 'execute_if_updated'
F:/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP =>routes =>environment
```

Contents of `environment.rb`

```
# Load the Rails application.
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the Rails application.
Rails.application.initialize!
```

When I insert config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"] in your config/application.rb, and run rake routes, it gives the error `can't convert Symbol into String`

[image]

Upgrading the grape version, I got this error:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post the error trace including the line(s) of code where the error is happening?

Comment: @Surya: I have updated the error above. Please check.

Comment: Add this line: `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` in your config/application.rb file and then try again?

Comment: Where do i place this code in the application.rb. I placed it inside class. It gives some other error now.

Comment: Place it inside: `class Application < Rails::Application` . did you try? Does it work? What is the output?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, it gives some error. I shall edit the error in the question. In short, it gives `can't convert Symbol into String` error

Comment: Where's that error coming from? can you post that too?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of the error for your reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62964/discussion-between-learner-and-surya).

Comment: @Surya: Add the answer we discussed and I shall mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion, you need to update your grape gem's version to 0.9.0 and then you need to add this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'grape', '0.9.0'
```

and then:

```
$ bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.11.0, the documentation says

> Rails
>
> Place API files into app/api. Rails expects a subdirectory that
>   matches the name of the Ruby module and a file name that matches the
>   name of the class. In our example, the file name location and
>   directory for Twitter::API should be app/api/twitter/api.rb.

Simple solution would be creating another api folder and moving entire files & dirs into app/api/api folder